# How to retrieve top N rows from each group in SQL with JOIN tables

Tags: mysql, group-by

I need a database with two tabels. I need to JOIN them, group the records and then display top 5 rows from each group. Here is my initial query without top N records:

```
SELECT customerId, itemId, count(itemId) as num FROM Orders JOIN OrderItems ON orderId=orderId ORDER BY num DESC GROUP BY customerId
```

I suppose I would need a ROWNUM and PARTITION BY here, but I have no idea how to combine them with JOIN tables. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To retrieve the top 5 rows per group in your query, you can use a subquery with the ROW_NUMBER function and a PARTITION BY clause.

```
  SELECT customerId, itemId, num
    FROM (
      SELECT customerId, itemId, num,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customerId ORDER BY num DESC) as rn
      FROM (
        SELECT customerId, itemId, count(itemId) as num
        FROM Orders
        JOIN OrderItems ON Orders.orderId = OrderItems.orderId
        GROUP BY customerId, itemId
      ) as subquery1
    ) as subquery2
    WHERE rn <= 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the 5 orders with the most items, you could use this:

```sql
SELECT TOP 5
  o.orderID, count(*)
FROM Order o INNER JOIN OrderItem oi on o.OrderID = oi.OrderID
GROUP BY o.OrderID
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
```

For displaying the top 5 items in each order, it is a bit more complex, because you cannot use windowed functions in `WHERE` or `ORDER BY`.
For this, you need a subquery to retrieve the ranking and sort/filter the result.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    oi.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY oi.OrderID ORDER BY oi.Something) as ranking
  FROM OrderItem oi
) tmp WHERE ranking < 6
ORDER BY tmp.OrderID, tmp.ranking
```

If that is not your intent, please give an example for your intended result.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).